# Is there a way to encrypt a drive with Truecrypt, and keep your data?

Tags: linux, truecrypt

Simple question, using the Truecrypt program, can I encrypt a hard drive without it deleting the data on the drive?

I know I can do this with Bitlocker on Windows, can I do the same with Truecrypt on Linux? The GUI wizard indicates otherwise.

Thanks

Comment: TrueCrypt only supports in place encryption for the system partition/disk (don't ask me why). If you're using only Linux, I wouldn't use TrueCrypt in the first place. It's main advantage is the windows support.

Answer (score 1):

@CodesinChaos's comment is correct:

> TrueCrypt only supports in place encryption for the system partition/disk (don't ask me why).

So if you have Windows installed on a system, and want to encrypt your C: drive, which would include your operating system, installed programs, and data saved to C:\Users, you can do this without loss of data or programs.

If you have an external drive, second internal hard drive, or separate partition on the same physical drive your C: drive lives on, and you want to encrypt that, you need to copy the data off first, set it up with Truecrypt, then copy the data back after it is mounted with Truecrypt.

Truecrypt does not do system partition encryption on Linux, so you are in the same situation as the second paragraph above.

Linux has had its own built-in full disk encryption for a while (dm-crypt/LUKS), so the fact that you can't do Truecrypt full-disk or system-disk encryption under Linux is not a big deal.  Debian and Ubuntu can both set up full-disk encryption during the installers.  I don't know of any "encrypt-in-place" tools for Linux (there may be some out there).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe either LUKS or TrueCrypt currently supports in-place encryption of a full volume.

The difficulty with in-place encryption of a drive is that the drive already occupies all available space.  Encrypting it with LUKS/dm-crypt or TrueCrypt without losing the data requires moving things around to make room for the encryption header.  Since LUKS is filesystem-agnostic and is traditionally implemented as a layer below the filesystem layer, I doubt it'll ever support in-place encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried TrueCrypt on Linux but have used it a lot on Windows and Mac. I'd assume the same concept / limitation applies for Linux.

When you choose 'Create a volume within a partition/drive', TrueCrypt **will erase all the data** in it (i.e. the partition or drive or device). It will ask for you confirmation first in the wizard flow.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Answer is no from experience but I can't find any relevant sources in the TC documentation to back up my answer.

Additionally TC only supports full disk encryption on Windows, to get FDE on Linux use an alternative such as dmcrypt.

You will have to back up your data onto another drive and copy it back over to the newly encrypted drive unfortunately. Also note that unlike TC full disk encryption on Windows, dmcrypt cannot be removed from a drive without removing all the data too.

I don't think these are particularly restrictive limitations but it's good to know.

Answer (score -2):

TrueCrypt Supports Windows operating system. You can Check this [tutorial](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/tutorial). The document states only for Windows.

But, Truecrypt supports Linux Operating System. You could Check out the [OS Specification](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/supported-operating-systems). But it is not enabled to encrypt a hard drive. Truecrypt provides good support for Windows to [encrypt the system](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/sys-encryption-supported-os#Y0). But not providing that much with Linux.

**FOR LINUX :**

You can use [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) utility for Linux environment. It is good and working great. Follow the [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/howto-linux-hard-disk-encryption-with-luks-cryptsetup-command/).

Comment: Downvoted for not actually answering the question - "can I keep my data?"

Comment: @immibis : Yes of course, You can keep your data safe.

Comment: Also the implied "how can I keep my data?"

Comment: @immibis : Luks using block level encryption system to protect data safe. Which is the same technique used in truecrypt to encrypt the data.